# Ubuntu 15.04 will NOT run on HP DV2845se with dual core AMD Turion and nvidia 630M graphics

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 15.04

I have been an Ubuntu user for about 5 years and have had Ubuntu on the subject laptop the entire time. Yes I have had some trials and tribulations with the nvidia hardware but always managed to make it run.

With 15.04(3.19 kernel) no matter what I do ( and I have been in all the trenches) the computer will either black screen with the recommended nvidia 304.125 driver or I get GPU lockup with nouveau on a clean install.

I have even done a clean install of 14.04 (on which it was running fine) but at the first update (kernel 3.16) here we go again with nouveau lock ups or nvidia black screens.

I have tried everything I can find over the last 2-3 weeks-all sorts of manual installs and NOTHING works.

Anybody got any suggestions? I am currently reduced to 12.04 as 14.04 will no longer run either.

Answer (score 0):

I had to drop back to Lubuntu from Ubuntu after the Ubuntu 14.04 updates left the system too glitchy.  The Nouveau driver worked under Lubuntu, but ran too hot, but the Nvidia 304.125 was better (still warm, but runnable).  Unity is the killer for you, try another desktop, and that might be your solution also.

---

I did succeed in getting Ubuntu 14.04 to run by installing xfce4 and removing all the unity packages.  Dual booting that now with Lubuntu, still deciding which I like better.  Getting xfce4 installed needed to be done at a virtual terminal since there was no usable GUI until unity was totally removed.  There did seem to be some sort of glitch on the Nvidia 304 driver install -- from the GUI additional drivers it looked like it worked, but checking the actual modules the only Nvidia driver was the frame buffer one, not the normal nvidia-304.  A simple apt-get --reinstall install on it did set things right, no idea what the problem was, but do check on what video module is in use as you are working on this (with lsmod).

Comment: I was thinking about doing that very thing. But it looks to me like Canonical broke something that really didn't need breaking. The wild thing here is this is a 2008 PC and I have a 2005 single core Acer laptop on which 15.04 runs just fine. But it is also ATI/AMD graphics.